# Refactoring conditional variable assignment

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I'm working on a project. Currently I have a fairly large conditional statement, that assigns a value to a variable based on some input parameters. So, I have something like this.

```
if some condition
  x = some value
elsif another condition
  x = a different value
  ...
```

What's the best way to refactor this? I'm hoping that I might end up with something like

```
x = some value if some condition || another value if another condition
```

Is there a pattern for this sort of thing?

Comment: Before we can tell you how to refactor, you need to tell us why you want to refactor this. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: `refactor = nil unless exist?(:unit_tests)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just put the assignment outside the if.

```
x = if some condition
  some value
elsif another condition
  a different value
```

Or you could use a Hash.

```
x = dict[some condition]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a pattern, but an operator. The one you're referring to is the ternary operator:

```
If Condition is true ? Then value X : Otherwise value Y
```

Here is an example:

```
speed = 90
speed > 55 ? puts("I can't drive 55!") : puts("I'm a careful driver")
```

Using the ternary statement is short, sweet, and does the job.

Comment: My conditional is longer than an if then else.

Comment: Then I'd stick with the `if/elsif` statement. There is nothing wrong with using those.

Comment: `puts (speed > 55) ? "I can't drive 55!" : "I'm a careful driver"`

Answer (score 1):

```
x = some condition ? some value : 
    another condition ? a different value : ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A conditional statement is also an expression, so one of the first things  you can do, if the variable is the same in each condition, is:

```
x = if cond1
  expr1
elsif cond2
  expr2
....
end
```

If the conditions are all states of a single expression, you can make this even neater, using a case statement.

However, the next most obvious re-factoring exercise is to get the big conditional isolated into a method, which should be fed the bare minimum data required to evaluate all the conditions and expressions.

E.g.

```
# Where conditional is currently, and x assigned, assuming the conditionals
# need a couple of variables . . .
x = foo param1, param2

# Elsewhere
private

def foo p1, p2
  if cond1
    expr1
  elsif cond2
    expr2
  ....
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refactor for code clarity and flexibility, consider the [replacing conditional with polymorphism](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html) refactor.

There's not enough detail in your question to go much further with recommendations, but this refactor will make your code base much more resistant to change.  If you receive a new requirement, it's bad form to break open the conditional and modify it (more prone to introducing bugs, more difficult to do); it's preferable to create a new object that you can plug into the existing codebase. This flexibility what the [Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) (the "O" in the SOLID acronym) describes.